# Cannot find module '@angular/http' Angular 9

Tags: angular

I am facing an error all of a sudden in a perfectly fine running application

Cannot find module '@angular/http'

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
```

I am using http to read a json file

```
 this.http.get('assets/env/env.json').pipe(map( res => res.json()))
```

Please help

Comment: try installing deps again `npm i`

Comment: Is the "of a sudden" an angular upgrade?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm No mate.. I did a package installation.. Then onwards this error happens... I am new in Angular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Http` was deprecated. Use `HttpClient`

```
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 3):

angular replaced the http module back in around angular 5 or 6. It's been deprecated for some time. You now need to use the `HttpClient` and `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http`

but be aware that the `Http` service and the `HttpClient` service have some important differences that may break your app if it was using `Http`

Answer (score 2):

`@angular/http` is depricated and in recent versions and is now removed from the generated `package.json` file, use HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'.